# Treeview inside a combo box WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a tree view inside a combo box.
When I select an item from tree view, the combo box displays like this 
"System.Windows.Controls.TreeView Items.Count:13"

How do I change the ComboBox's SelectedItem property so that i can display the right property. I basically want the selected TreeViewItem to set the SelectedItem of the ComboBox. Here is my xaml.

```
<ComboBox Name="CB" DropDownClosed="destTb_DropDownClosed">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <TreeView  Background="Transparent" Name="TV" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGroup}" 
                SelectedItemChanged="TV_SelectedItemChanged">
         <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" >
               <Grid>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
               </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
          </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     </TreeView>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `TreeView` inside a `ComboBox` instead of just a `TreeView`?

Comment: @nakiya When I click on the combo box it should open the tree view. Its the requirement.

Comment: So you want a CollapsibleTreeView that shows only the `SelectedItem` when collapsed. I would expect the `ComboBox` to be made for flat lists only, not for hierarchical data. Have a look at [the TreeView control's properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx), it may have the capabilities to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: @Martin, that could be useful because of available space. Imagine drop-down list of parent-child tasks. In case of TreeView usage, that would require a lot of space. Combobox which displays data hierarchically would be much nicer...